# How to make emacs style ASCII-art table in Mail?

Tags: emacs

Is there a app available to do this?

```
 +-----------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
 |     Command     |          Description           |   Key Binding   |
 +-----------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
 |  forward-char   |Move point right N characters   |       C-f       |
 |                 |(left if N is negative).        |                 |
 |                 |                                |                 |
 |                 |On reaching end of buffer, stop |                 |
 |                 |and signal error.               |                 |
 +-----------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
 |  backward-char  |Move point left N characters    |       C-b       |
 |                 |(right if N is negative).       |                 |
 |                 |                                |                 |
 |                 |On attempt to pass beginning or |                 |
 |                 |end of buffer, stop and signal  |                 |
 |                 |error.                          |                 |
 +-----------------+--------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What's wrong with using Emacs to write the mail and then copy&paste it into a new mail?

Comment: Is your problem that the recipient of the email will not see the formatting correctly?  You may need to tell them to switch to a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by patrix you could do that in Emacs. To automate it, you should use QuickCursor (available in the Mac App Store), and a special build of Emacs, which you can do by checking out the latest source code from ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest and then using the patches available from ftp://ftp.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/emacs

Instruction on how to build are available in the archive containing the patch file. Once you've done that, editing between Emacs and Mail (or whatever else), should be extremely easy.

Comment: Or use Aquamacs to avoid compilation.

Comment: In the Mac App Store page of [Quickcursor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickcursor/id404035899?mt=12) the developer says that "* Please note: Self-compiling Aquamacs works for many users but not all. The current precompiled binaries from the Aquamacs website do not work due to compiler issues we cannot control.", so I assumed Aquamacs doe not work out of the box as well.

Comment: Ah, Quickcursor ties into Emacs directly. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a table in HTML and attaching it? I just emailed one to myself (with Mail), and I had to click on the attachment to view it in a web browser (Safari). But this is easier to maintain as the formatting is done for you.